# Parsear string ip clase c python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hola estoy tratando de separar cada uno de los octetos de una dirección ip cualquiera pero no lo consigo.

Tengo esto, que no funciona:

```
j = 0
ip = "a.b.c.d"
for i in ip:
    j = j + 1
    if str(i)==".":
        l = ip[:j]
        print l
```

Comment: Hola @ellipsys, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Me gustaría saber cuál es el resultado esperado de tu programa.

Comment: @toledano tiene como salida algo como                                                         a.                                                                                                                             a.b                                                                                                                                           a.b.c

Comment: Aunque estés trabajando con [tag:python-2.7], tal vez deberías empezar a usar el módulo [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html) de python3. Existe [backport para python2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2-ipaddress).

Answer (score 2):

Buenas.

Intenta dividir la cadena por el carácter "." :

```
ip = "192.168.0.123"
result = ip.split(".")
for x in result:
    print x
```

Comment: Ok, funciono. Si quisiera declarar cada octeto como una variable para luego utilizarlas en otro ciclo, tengo que utilizar funciones verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo quieres como concepto del uso y manejo de cadenas de texto, puedes usar esta línea:

```
ip = 'a.b.c.d'
clase_c = '.'.join(ip.split('.')[:3])
```

Usa la cadena `'.'` como unión de las primeras tres partes (*slices* le dicen en Python) de la cadena `ip` dividida por el carácter `'.'`.

> **lambdas**
>   Estoy seguro que hay una forma más *pythónica* de hacer esto usando lambdas. Ojalá un experto aporte su opinión.

Si quieres trabajar con direcciones IP, redes, etc, te recomiendo la biblioteca [`netaddr`](https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html).

Comment: Como más *pythónico* pienso en las expresiones regulares (*módulo re*), pero no veo qué podrían aportar las funciones lambdas aquí.